# I can't locate the source of my 'NoneType' error in my version of Pong

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, pong

I posted a version of Pong to another popular site yesterday and got a lot of advice on how I can clean it up, and got a lot of tips in general. One is that all coordinates should be tuples.

I've been rewriting it all morning to try to improve it(specifically with the tuple thing), but I'm stuck with a NoneType somewhere, which I can't find for the life of me.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "C:\Users\Jassie\Desktop\Pygame_Pong_v2.py", line 172, in 
>      my_ball.update()
>    File "C:\Users\Jassie\Desktop\Pygame_Pong_v2.py", line 64, in update
>      self.pos = (self.pos[0] + self.vel[0], self.pos[1] + self.vel[1])
>   TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

```
def update(self):
    #Update ball's position
    self.pos = (self.pos[0] + self.vel[0], self.pos[1] + self.vel[1])
    self.pos_x = int(self.pos[0])
    self.pos_y = int(self.pos[1])
```

There is the error and the bit of code referenced in the error.

https://github.com/Jassie411/pong

There is a link to the full code if anyone could take a look and help me out. I have looked at the code all morning(since about 4AM actually), looking at where the initial velocity tuple comes from, where the initial position tuple comes from, and where they're going. I just can't see where the NoneType is coming from. I've also tried completely rewriting that part of it, but I can't solve this myself.

If someone could please help me with this, I would be so grateful. I know after I get past this I can finish the rest of it simply. But this error is killing me.

Edit: Sorry, I should probably describe the behavior and such. I know it's an error with either the position or velocity attribute becoming None, but I don't know which it is, and I don't know where.

What I do know, is that it only throws the error when the ball hits the gutter or paddle. It doesn't matter which it hits, it throws the same error either way. Naturally I thought it would be in the code that checks that collision, but I can't find it there.

Comment: simple print statements where the error was originating would have helped you see which value was returning nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `spawn_ball` function:

```
def spawn_ball(direction = random.choice('01')):
    #direction should always be left if AI is enabled for paddle2.
    #0 is left, 1 is right
    if direction == 0:
        return (random.uniform(1.0, 3.0) * -1, random.uniform(1.0, 3.0) * -1)
    elif direction == 1:
        return (random.uniform(1.0, 3.0), random.uniform(1.0, 3.0) * -1)
```

First of all you shouldn't initialize default variables like this. `random.choice('01')` is evaluated once, when function object is created. So default direction will always be the same. But what is causing your error is that `0 != '0'`. So when you call `spawn_ball` without arguments no `if` statement is matched and function returns `None`.

Here's correct variant:

```
def spawn_ball(direction=None):
    if direction is None:
        direction = random.choice((0, 1))
    #direction should always be left if AI is enabled for paddle2.
    #0 is left, 1 is right
    if direction == 0:
        return (random.uniform(1.0, 3.0) * -1, random.uniform(1.0, 3.0) * -1)
    elif direction == 1:
        return (random.uniform(1.0, 3.0), random.uniform(1.0, 3.0) * -1)
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer in the main post. I know it has to be one or the other, but I can't find where it's becoming None.

I should also probably mention the behavior of it. The game starts, but as soon as it passes the gutter or hits the paddle, it throws the error. So naturally I think it's in that code, but I still can't figure out how it's becoming None

Comment: I changed my answer, hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much. I would have never found that. Some of the advice on the other site was to use random.choice, and I guess I didn't quite understand the documentation.

Seriously, that is greatly appreciated

Edit: Turns out to not be the solution. still getting the same error

Comment: Ignore the edit in my last post. It was the solution, but I was setting direction to 'left' and 'right' when the ball hit the gutter, and that was also causing spawn_ball to return None